# How to give CIFAR-10 as an input to MLP

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am a noob in machine learning and trying to build a classifier using keras by following this tutorial [machine learning mastery tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/object-recognition-convolutional-neural-networks-keras-deep-learning-library/)

I want to build a classifier based on MLP like in [classification of MNIST using MLP](https://machinelearningmastery.com/handwritten-digit-recognition-using-convolutional-neural-networks-python-keras/) for CIFAR-10 data set.Like in MNIST data set the 28*28 images to a 784 vector is given as a input to the neural network.
Like wise how should I frame the data in CIFAR-10 should it be changed in the 36*36 pixels rgb values to an array? or what type of array should I make to give as a input to the MLP network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MNIST has 28x28 pixel greyscale images, so there are $28\times28 = 784$ features per image.

CIFAR10 contains colour images that are 32x32 pixels. At first glance it may seem like there are only $32\times32 = 1024$ features per image, but there are red, blue and green channels in the image, which means each image is actually $3\times32\times32 = 3072$ features.

Usually, these channels are arranged as three separate 32x32 pixel images, rather than a single 32x32 image with RGB pixels. In keras, you can load the CIFAR10 dataset like so:

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
```

However, this will load the train and test dataset in the shape `(num_samples, 3, 32, 32)`. In order to input these into an MLP, we need to flatten the channels and pixel arrays to form an array of shape `(num_samples, 3072)`, just like with MNIST. We can do this in python like so:

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 3072)
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 3072)
```

Comment: How does this reshape work I read in documentation that the np.reshpae(array_to_be_reshaped ,new shape dim,order).Can you please explain your reshape   https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: @Boris You could do it that way too, by using `x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1, 3072))`. They are both equivalent.